# how to call multiple function of same class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am declaring a class Response with multiple instance method of this class like the code below but I am getting an error throwing from the output: `Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payload')`. I want to get results from what I am calling to get. How can I do it?

```js
class Response {

  output({
    message = null,
    payload = null,
    data = null
  }) {
    return {
      message,
      payload,
      data
    }
  }

  message(message) {
    this.output({
      message
    })
  }

  payload(payload) {
    this.output({
      payload
    })
  }

  data(data) {
    this.output({
      data
    })
  }

}

const response = new Response();

console.log(
  response
  .message('my message')
  .payload('my payload')
  .data('my data')
);
// expected result: { message: 'my message', payload: 'my payload', data: 'my data' }

console.log(
  response
  .message('my message')
  .payload('my payload')
);
// expected result: { message: 'my message', payload: 'my payload', data: null }

console.log(
  response
  .payload('my payload')
);
// expected result: { message: null, payload: 'my payload', data: null }
```

Comment: Your code expects these methods to return a `response` instance, but they don't have a `return` statement, so they return undefined. Chaining methods is thus not possible.

Comment: @trincot Is there any other way for me to do that?

Comment: To do what exactly? You want the chaining to work? Then make sure to `return`.

Comment: @trincot I did but still getting error: `Error: response.message(...).payload is not a function`

Comment: It is not clear what in this code is under your control, and what you cannot change. Is the implementation of the `Response` class completely in your hands?

Comment: `this.output()` doesn't do anything but return an object. But you'e not using the returned value in the methods that call it. What are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: @trincot  this implementation still not working as expected

Comment: Like I said, it is not clear what your assignment is here. Please clarify.

Comment: @trincot  sorry, I don't know what words to use to describe it. maybe i want to make chainable methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand, you are trying to make chainable methods (similar to what the String class does.)

To make chainable methods, you have almost done the right thing, except in the `output` method, you return a plain object. This isn't right because then it just returns an object and not an **instance of the `Response` class**.

So, the `output` method should return something like:

```js
output({
    message = null,
    payload = null,
    data = null
  }) {
    return new Response({
      message,
      payload,
      data
    })
  }
```

Additionally, you should also have a constructor that accepts the required parameters and stores them in a global object (like a state variable).

That would make your class look like:

```js
class Response {

  state = {
    message: null,
    payload: null,
    data: null
  }
  
  constructor(params) {
    // be careful, params can also be null when calling the constructor with no arguments. 
    // handle it accordingly
    this.state = params
  }

  output({
    message = null,
    payload = null,
    data = null
  }) {
    return new Response({
      message,
      payload,
      data
    })
  }

  message(message) {
    this.output({
      message
    })
  }

  payload(payload) {
    this.output({
      payload
    })
  }

  data(data) {
    this.output({
      data
    })
  }

}
```

Additionally, to make it even more efficient, you can replace the `new Response()` call in the `output` function to be:

```js
output({
    message = null,
    payload = null,
    data = null
  }) {
    this.state = {
       message,
       payload,
       data
    }
    return this // this returns an instance of the class
}
```

This covers your back if you should change the class name in the future, you need not come back to the `output` function and change the `return new Response()` to `return new NewClass()` everytime.

Hope it helped!

Comment: I would add that this is called a 'Builder design pattern'

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty  Hello bro, I tried it but I got `undefined`, please help me check this code above at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-sregrz?file=index.js

Comment: You are getting the result just fine. You aren't getting `undefined` but the entire `Response` instance logged out. Check it once again.